# Matcher.replaceAll() removes backslash even when I escape it. Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have functionality in my app that should replace some text in json (I have simplified it in the example). Their replacement may contain escaping sequences like `\n \b \t` etc. which can break the json string when I try to build json with Jackson. So I decided to use Apache's solution - `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()` to escape all escaping sequences. But
`Matcher.replaceAll()` removes backslashes which added by `escapeJava()`

There is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"test2\": \"Hello toReplace \\\"test\\\" world\"}";

    String replacedJson = Pattern.compile("toReplace")
            .matcher(json)
            .replaceAll(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("replacement \n \b \t"));

    System.out.println(replacedJson);
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"test2": "Hello replacement \n \b \t \"test\" world"}
```

Actual Output:

```
{"test2": "Hello replacement n b t \"test\" world"}
```

Why does `Matcher.replaceAll()` removes backslahes while `System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("replacement \n \b \t"));` returns correct output - `replacement \n \b \t`

Comment: Do you really need a regex to do this? It looks like a simple replacement.

Comment: Directly operating on JSON like this is eventually going to fail somewhere.  For instance, it is perfectly legal for JSON to contain `"\u0074\u006f\u0052\u0065\u0070\u006c\u0061\u0063\u0065"` instead of `"toReplace"`.  It’s really better to use a true JSON parser and perform substitutions on values, not raw JSON.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for your advice, but I'm not shure that I got you idea. Could you please share an example of solution which you suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\n")` allows you to transform the single newline character `\n` into two characters: `\` and `n`.

`\` is a special character in pattern replacements though, from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and **backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string**.

To have them taken as literal characters, you need to escape it via `Matcher.quoteReplacement`, from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String):

> Returns a literal replacement `String` for the specified `String`. This method produces a `String` that will work as a literal replacement `s` in the `appendReplacement` method of the `Matcher` class. The `String` produced will match the sequence of characters in `s` treated as a literal sequence. **Slashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) will be given no special meaning.**

So in your case:

```
.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("replacement \n \b \t")))
```

Comment: "\ is a special character in pattern replacements though" oh, I didn't know about that, so it is the reason why replaceAll() removes backslash, because backslash interpreted differently in regex. I got it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want a literal backslash in `replaceAll`, you need to escape it. You can find this in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` will escape a string suitable for use in Java source code - but it won't allow you to use unescaped strings in your source code.

```
"replacement \n \b \t"
             ^ new line
                 ^ backspace
                    ^ tab
```

If you want literal backslashes in a regular Java string, you need:

```
"replacement \\n \\b \\t"
```

Because this is a java string of the replace part of a regular expression for `replaceAll`, you need:

```
"replacement \\\\n \\\\b \\\\t"
```

Try:

```
    String replacedJson = Pattern.compile("toReplace")
            .matcher(json)
            .replaceAll("replacement \\\\n \\\\b \\\\t")
```

Comment: result the same, it doesn't work

Comment: Apologies, try the updated answer

Comment: yes. it is working. But is there a method which will escape all escaping sequence for me? Because the replacement comes different every time

Comment: I've clarified a bit and linked you to the documentation. You'll need to follow the rules there - I'm not sure if there is an existing method provided.

Comment: Update - the other answer has a better method for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `\` as well using `Matcher.quoteReplacement()`.

```java
public static String replaceAll(String json, String regex, String replace) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex)
                  .matcher(json)
                  .replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(replace)));
}
```